# Most energy-dense commercial battery available

Tags: energy, density

What's the most energy-dense and currently commercially available chemical battery technology? Would it be the Lithium-Ion Polymer or has it been surpassed already?

There's is a chemical non-rechargeable battery which is more energy-dense than LiPo, even if it's less power-dense?

I'm trying to have a general sense of the current state-of-the-art technology, as the Wikipedia articles and tables seems to be very dated.

Edit: I meant "dense" as in respect to mass. I believe that "specific energy" would be the right terminology.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Energy_densities_of_common_energy_storage_materials) has a list of common battery types with energy densities.

Lithium ion primary batteries appear to have the highest specific energy at around 300 Wh/kg. Lead-acid batteries have a specific energy around 10% that of lithium-ion batteries, but are extremely reliable (depth of discharge, self-discharge, etc.), and do not have nearly the same heating/fire issues (though they can explode if you mess with them), which is one of the reasons they have endured so long in automotive applications.

[More exotic chemistries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_battery#Chemistries) have higher specific energies, but I am unsure as to whether they are available to the average consumer.

Comment: Lithium-air batteries are NOT production-ready.

Answer (score -3):

**Not neccesarily truth, I don't have exhausting knowledge in the area**

> What's the most energy-dense and currently commercially available chemical battery technology

**Assuming we talk about energy per mass unit.**

In case one doesn't care about reversibility, it is air-metal batteries (say, alumunium-air). In case one does, it is probably Lithium-sulfide batteries.

Both are inferiour to common internal combustion engine, though.

**Assuming we are talking about power per mass unit**

Lead batteries are close to top, AFAIK. Otherwise they would be pushed out from cars already.

Comment: Do you know of any commercially available air-metal battery?

Comment: http://www.microbattery.com/zinc-air-battery-specs || zinc-air batteries are definitely available, see the link. They are faaar inferrior to potential of aluminium-air batteries, but still beat any rechargeable Li batteries. Aluminium-air batteries were announced to be produced this spring and are said to be used in various prototypes, but no other relevant traces in the web were found.

Comment: This would be a decent answer if it contained some actual numbers not vague hand waving opinions and it referenced whether the tech was a prototype or a commercial product.

Comment: @matt_black I converted it to community wiki, feel free to fill in the details. The numbers can be pulled from Wikipedia.